# Freshdesk email command

Tags: email, freshdesk

I have created a freshdesk account and support also. If I send an email to create a new ticket it won't create a ticket with this code:

```
Mt delemeter is 
@Simonsays
```

My email body is

```
@Simonsays "status":"pending", "priority":"medium", "agent":"Test Agent" @Simonsays
```

I am receiving a ticket but It is not change  the values assigned there in Ticket Properties. If I do have any errors in Email Command, please sort it out

Comment: Can you please describe more about your environment. I know freshdesk, but I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Commands on tickets where you are the requester do not work.